# ListView not shown where layout is too tall

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to make a frontend in android for a social network I've been doing and for some reason my ListView for the comments is not showing when the photo is a square. I saw that all the comments are showing if the photo is smaller, so it leaves some space to the comments, but the list view is getting stacked under the next view or just not shown.

The parent RecyclerView is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wonerwhy.oddy.smps.helper.Posts">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: designer view[![]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivAvatar"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ListView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lvComments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivPost"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Next up this is the item in the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvUser"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The post has many comments as shown in the left, but the android app fails to show them

[image: none]

Tho if the ratio is less than 1:1

[image: success]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem:
I found out that nesting a ListView into a RecyclerView while having the layout height on wrap content will automatically size it down to 0 and i figured that even if I would want to use a list view the scrolling would be overwritten by the RecyclerView scrolling, so I bailed on the ListView (see you later). 
Instead of that I used a LinearLayout and I populated it in the onBindViewHolder method of the RecyclerView.